# How to debug frozen md raid?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm, software-raid, md

We have an old backup server with lots of disks and one mount with `md` raid 5 setup has now frozen. How to diagnose the problem and get it to running again? I would like to avoid restarting the whole system because only one subsystem requires this specific mount point.

Diagnostics this far:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
...
md0 : active raid5 sdn1[2] sdm1[1] sdo1[4] sdl1[0] sdg1[5] sda1[6]
      29301952000 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [==========>..........]  check = 54.4% (3191189500/5860390400) finish=3314902.0min speed=13K/sec
      bitmap: 0/44 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

and this doesn't progress even a little bit even though I already adjusted `/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max` and `/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min` and waited for an hour.

However, according to `mdadm` everything seems fine:

```
# mdadm --query --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Jun 15 23:50:50 2016
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 29301952000 (27944.52 GiB 30005.20 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 5860390400 (5588.90 GiB 6001.04 GB)
      Raid Devices : 6
     Total Devices : 6
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Mon Jul  5 01:42:59 2021
             State : active, checking 
    Active Devices : 6
   Working Devices : 6
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

      Check Status : 54% complete

              Name : examplehost:md0  (local to host examplehost)
              UUID : ed0000c4:47000085:8000006f:221938f5
            Events : 404407

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8      177        0      active sync   /dev/sdl1
       1       8      193        1      active sync   /dev/sdm1
       2       8      209        2      active sync   /dev/sdn1
       4       8      225        3      active sync   /dev/sdo1
       6       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1
       5       8       97        5      active sync   /dev/sdg1
```

And the underlying devices work just fine: I tested running

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/tmp/test.img bs=1M count=1
```

for every disk in this raid and got the expected start of disk with normal response time.

So it seems that the underlying hardware is working just fine but the md raid has frozen in practice. The actual mount point of this raid doesn't give any errors but seems to never respond to any IO requests. Even a simple `ls -la` hangs forever.

The `journalctl --since "7 days ago" | grep "blocked for more than"` tells that there has been slowness in `md1` but `md0` doesn't appear in the system logs even though it doesn't respond at all.

```
Jul 04 01:20:14 examplehost kernel: INFO: task jbd2/md1-8:2262 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Jul 04 01:38:21 examplehost kernel: INFO: task jbd2/md1-8:2262 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Jul 04 02:04:32 examplehost kernel: INFO: task jbd2/md1-8:2262 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

The mount point of `md1` works just fine so that must have been just too much load for that night.

**Can you provide any hints how to fix this mount? I'd obviously prefer suggestions that can fix it without restarting the whole server.** If you can suggest something that can fix this without unmounting the filesystem it would be even better. I first assumed that it was hardware hang but that doesn't seem to be the case this same.

I think this has happened once before and in that case the server was just rebooted. However, I'd like to understand the real issue so that I can apply a real fix. The system is running Linux kernel version 5.4.119 in case it makes a difference.

Comment: Real hostname and UUID has been redacted.

Comment: `smartctl -x /dev/sdX` also says that all devices are okay. The underlying drives are Western Digital Red 6 TB drives but I would guess that's not related to the issue at hand.

Comment: I also tried to run `echo "idle" > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action` but that too just hangs.

Comment: This didn't help me but could help somebody else with similar symptoms: https://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg41039.html

Comment: I also tried `sudo fuser -M -m /path/to/md0/mount -k -9` that that couldn't make the `md0` not busy either. I couldn't figure out any way to make `md0` and underlying devices non-busy so I had to restart the whole system in the end. If I just needed to make the mount point available, I could have used `umount -l /path/to/md0/mount` but that wouldn't make the raid available for remounting – however, I needed the raid volume back to online. Running just `sync` from command line did hang, too!

Comment: The system reboot took about half and hour but things seem to be working again. Reading through the `journalctl` after reboot tells that even systemd failed to kill frozen `md0` parts: e.g. `systemd: Killing process 1203568 (rsync) with signal SIGKILL.` followed by `systemd: Failed with result 'timeout'.` and later `Killing process 805983 (mdcheck) with signal SIGKILL.` and `mdcheck_start.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.` It took the system 6 minutes to finally reboot and the reboot took 8 minutes extra for something unknown according to `journalctl`.

Comment: According to `journalctl` after magically losing 8 minutes to something, the next boot took extra 2.5 minutes to run `fsck` on the volume that was mounted `md0` during the hang and returned with clean after recovering journal. So the total time the reboot took was around 20 minutes. I still don't understand where those extra 8 minutes went before kernel started to boot but I'd guess Ubuntu initrd did something before booting the kernel. I did the whole setup remote so I don't know what the local console was displaying for that 8 minutes.

Comment: You should check journalctl or your kernel log for any error messages while reading or writing to any of the drives in your raid array.   maybe check Western Digital's web site to see if there are any firmware updates for those drives (and google the model number to see if there are any known problems).   When drives stall or hang, I tend to suspect either the drives or the controller (or motherboard) they're plugged in to are either failing or buggy.

Comment: You said that it works ok with `dd`, but the example you gave only showed reading just 1MB of data from one drive.  Does it hang when you run something more I/O-intensive like `for d in /dev/sd{n,m,o,l,g,a}1; do dd if="$d" of=/dev/null & done` to read lots of data from all drives at once?

Comment: Or use `dd if=/dev/md0 of=/dev/null`.  or try `bonnie++` or `fio` or anything else that thrashes the raid array.  Also check the SATA and power connectors on the drives, make sure they're securely plugged in.  It's possible that a connector is loose and the vibrations from heavy load is causing "random" disconnects.

Comment: And make sure that the power supply has enough spare capacity to provide enough power to all drives at once in addition to motherboard, cpu, gpu, ram, and whatever else is installed (this is unlikely to be the problem, but is worth checking if you can't find any other problem. Check the datasheet for your drive model to find out how much power it uses when reading & writing...probably around 5W per drive).

Comment: I did the `dd` for every drive to make sure that kernel is able to access the drives but only gave the command line once. If this happens again, I'll also try `dd if=/dev/md0` for sure. I don't know how I missed that test. There were no errors of any kind in the `journalctl` from `md0` so it was working "all ok but a bit slow" according to kernel. From the behavior I saw, I would expect that `dd if=/dev/md0 of=/dev/null` would have stalled without errors. The system is working just fine after rebooting so I don't think it's a hardware failure.

Comment: A shot in the dark: some kernel hangs can be fixed with kernel flag `iommu=pt`. I saw the problem with AMD CPU which does have IOMMU hardware.

Comment: The `&` in the for loop makes it run `dd` multiple times in the background, i.e. they'd all be running at once.  This will make sure the drives are all running at the same time.   It's not a comprehensive test, though, because there are no random seeks OR a mix of reads and writes, it's all just sequential reads.   that's why i suggested running other programs to thrash the raid array.   rsync would be great for that, which may be why it triggered the original problem.

Comment: The normal workload for that hardware is running multiple rsync routines in parallel and in addition it runs crap called HitachiHDS for additional off-site remote backup. So it's seeing high loads daily. It syncs changes in about 35 TB dataset in and another 35 TB dataset out daily.

Comment: If changing the kernel's iommu setting fixes it, that indicates that your motherboard needs to be replaced with something that isn't broken.  Or, maybe just update the BIOS with a non-broken version.   How old is the motherboard?   What kind (brand, model) of SATA ports does it have? (some motherboards have 4, 6, or 8 ports provided by the CPU's chipset and a few more that are whatever cheap junk they can find).   If the m/b is relatively "new" (i.e. within the last 5 years or so), it's probably OK.

Comment: I don't know if the `iommu` setting affects the problem. The problem seems to appear randomly about twice a year so testing any change is pretty slow. The idea for `iommu` setting came from this kernel bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683 – I haven't tried to add this flag but added it for future readers as an extra info.

Comment: BTW, if you want to greatly reduce the IO load from backups, I recommend switching to ZFS and using snapshots and `zfs send` for syncing and backups.   When I converted from mdadm raid to ZFS (over 10 years ago), the nightly backup jobs that used to take **hours** with `rsync` were completed in **minutes** with `zfs send`.  And the snapshots gave me a versioned history without a horrendous performance-killing link farm as with  programs like `rdiff-backup` or `backuppc`.

Comment: ZFS `send` is only usable if both the source and target systems use ZFS. For our case there're about 8 source systems with various filesystems on each and the off-site backup cannot use ZFS.

Comment: Depends.  True enough if you want to pipe `zfs send` into `zfs recv` to get a synced, duplicate mountable filesystem on the other end.   Not true if all you want is to archive or backup the snapshots (`zfs send` is just a data stream. can be saved as a file or dumped to tape or something), but restoring would require additional steps (to retrieve the snapshot dumps and process them in the right order - oldest to newest)

Comment: The problem hasn't reappeared after the reboot and I've now completed background mdadm `check` for all RAIDs in the system without a problem. I currently think I was unlucky enough to hit some kernel bug. The system is running with ECC RAM so I would guess it wasn't caused by memory error either.